# matplotlib axes3d radiobutton not able to update the plot

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create a 3d bar plot with radio buttons using matplotlib. However, the plot is not getting updated. A simple print command like 'print(plt.xticks())' returns an empty array!!

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
edf = np.random.randn(300).reshape(100,3)

eclus = np.linspace(1,5,5).reshape(5,1)
edim = (int)(edf.shape[0]/eclus.shape[0])

eclus = np.tile(eclus,(edim,1))

esam = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([edf,eclus], axis=1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15])
radio = RadioButtons(rax, [0,1,2])

def bar_3d(metric):
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(esam[int(metric)], esam[3],bins = 5)
    xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1] + 0.25, yedges[:-1] + 0.25, indexing="ij")
    xpos = xpos.ravel()
    ypos = ypos.ravel()
    zpos = 0
    # Construct arrays with the dimensions for the bars.
    dx = 1.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
    dy = 0.9 * np.ones_like(zpos)
    dz = hist.ravel()

    ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx ,dy ,dz)
    ax.set_xlabel(metric)
    ax.set_ylabel('Clusters')
    ax.set_yticks(range(5), minor=False)
    print(plt.xticks())
    plt.draw()
radio.on_clicked(bar_3d)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

What am I missing? Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT:
I'm using matplotlib 3.1.1 and the code doesn't work in either spyder or jupyter notebooks.

Comment: The fact that an empty array is printed shouldn't bother you; that's expected. But the figure should update of course. How/where are you running this code? Which version of matplotlib?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm using matplotlib 3.1.1 and the code doesn't work in either spyder or jupyter notebooks.

Comment: You are creating new bars every time the button is clicked. Could it be that the new bars are hidden below the original bars?

Comment: For what it's worth, your code works for me on matplotlib 3.1.1 using the `%matplotlib notebook` backend, but bars keep being added as I was suggesting above

Comment: And that's exactly I want to avoid:  the plot should be drawn again

Comment: You need to use an interactive backend for interactivity to work. If you want to clear the axes, `ax.clear()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks a lot. Can you please move your comment to answer?